# I had a very wet dream and woke up . Masturbated to avoide bad thoughts during fast

Tags: sawm, masturbation

I had a very wet dream and woke up while about to ejuculate.Then tried sleeping but had really bad thoughts,to avoid those bad thoughts i rubbed and masturbated.. Whats the ruling for me now? Im regretting and feeling ashamed as i was having a really great ramadaan,please somone guide

Comment: Masturbation during fasting (daytime) which leads to ejaculation breaks the fast and Qada is required. According to some schools Kaffara is also required. This has already been covered in questions on this site and elsewhere, please do  your research before asking.

Answer (score 0):

If the masturbation ended with Ejaculation then your fast was broken and the Kaffarah needs to be paid.
Which is to either;
A) Fast for 60 days
B) Feed 60 poor people like Fidhya (approx £2.50 - £3.00 per person)

If no ejaculation took place then it is still a sin and you need to repent.

Either way you need to repent and seek forgiveness from Allah. But one requires Kaffarah and the other doesn't because if you didn't ejaculate then you didn't actually break your fast.

Hope this helps.

Also advice once you sincerely seek forgiveness for something BELIEVE that Allah has forgiven you.
Don't underestimate Allahs mercy! The Shaiytain tricks us sometimes to make us think that Allah wont forgive us and then we go further astray. So never doubt the Rahmah of Allah.

May Allah keeps us steadfast and forgive the sins of the Muslims.
Aamewn

Comment: It would be better if you could share evidences to support your claims.